# How to add custom fonts to jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have been researching this for quite some time now and I have tried all of the answers on here and everywhere Google led me, but I can't get custom fonts to work with jsPDF. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use addFont() function to load various fonts . Then you can use a font by setFont() function

```
doc.addFont()
doc.setFont()
```

For example:

```
doc.addFont('ArialMS', 'Arial', 'normal');
doc.setFont('Arial');
doc.text(50,100,'Hello World');
```

If you have any issue in this answer , please comment or reply .thanks

Comment: Does it retrieve fonts from the "@font-face" in my css or do I need to import the font any other way? I saw a lot of old answers about converting .ttf files to base64 or .js files and then importing them, do I need to do this or is it as simple as adding whatever has been added via "@font-face" in my css?

Comment: see above comment